# How to find footer control in foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I have Datalist and I am not able to find the footer controls in foreach loop. Any help?

```
protected void btnactualapprove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataListItem dli in dtaddedOrderItem.Items)
         {
               DataList dtaddedsubserviceitem = (DataList)dli.FindControl("dtaddedsubserviceitem");
                foreach (DataListItem subdli in dtaddedsubserviceitem.Items)
                {
                   DataList dtsuggestedlist = (DataList)subdli.FindControl("dtsuggestedlist");
                    if (dtsuggestedlist != null)
                        {
                          // not comming inside
                        }
                  }
         }
    }
```

I am not able to find `dtsuggestedlist` which is in the footer of `dtaddedsubserviceitem` datalist.

Here all time I am getting `dtsuggestedlist` as null.

Structure is like as below

```
Datalist dtaddedOrderItem start
<ItemTemplate>
   Datalist dtsuggestedlist start
     <ItemTemplate>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <FooterTemplate>
        Datalist dtsuggestedlist start
        Datalist dtsuggestedlist end
     </FooterTemplate>
   Datalist dtsuggestedlist end
</ItemTemplate>
Datalist dtaddedOrderItem end
```

I am not able to find dtsuggestedlist which is in footer of dtsuggestedlist

Brief

```
<asp:DataList ID="dtaddedOrderItem" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DataList ID="dtaddedsubserviceitem" runat="server" >
           <ItemTemplate>
           </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                 <asp:DataList ID="dtsuggestedlist" runat="server" >
                     <ItemTemplate>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:DataList>
             </FooterTemplate>
      </asp:DataList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>

  <asp:Button ID="btnactualapprove" OnClick="btnactualapprove_Click" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a `foreach` because that will only enumerate items which type is `Item`/`AlternatingItem` and skip the header/footer etc. But you can use `Controls`.

This should work(in general):

```
DataListItem footer = (DataListItem)dataList.Controls[dataList.Controls.Count - 1];
```

and this in your special case of nested DataLists:

```
protected void btnactualapprove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataListItem dli in dtaddedOrderItem.Items)
    {
        DataList dl = (DataList)dli.FindControl("dtaddedsubserviceitem");
        DataListItem footer = (DataListItem)dl.Controls[dl.Controls.Count - 1];
        DataList dtsuggestedlist = (DataList)footer.FindControl("dtsuggestedlist");
        // ...
    }
}
```

> Can u answer me how to find header?

Yes:

```
DataListItem header = (DataListItem)dl.Controls[0];
```

Comment: Can u answer me how to find header?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach (DataListItem item in datalist1.Items)
{
   if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
   {
       Label lbl = (Label)item.FindControl("Label1");
   }
}
```

Use below modified code:

```
DataListItem footer = (DataListItem)DataList1.Controls[DataList1.Controls.Count - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

To get footer template on button clicked, iterate from `Controls` of DataList which will allow you to check the footer of DataList:

```
foreach (DataListItem item in dtaddedOrderItem.Items)
{
    DataList dtaddedsubserviceitem = (DataList)item.FindControl("dtaddedsubserviceitem");

    foreach(Control control in dtaddedsubserviceitem.Controls)
    {
        DataListItem item = (DataListItem)control;

        if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
        {
            DataList dtsuggestedlist = (DataList)footer.FindControl("dtsuggestedlist");
            if(dtsuggestedlist != null)
            {
                // do your code here
            }
        }
    }
}
```